# ListView scroll performance on some screen resolutions

Tags: java, android

I wrote some code to load JSON and show it in a ListView (that part is working), but my problem is that when I try to scroll my ListView on some devices it has problems. Specifically on the Nexus S device it works perfectly, but I tested it on other devices (e.g. Nexus 4, Nexus 7) and on these devices, the ListView has erratic render lag (when i try to scroll it).

On the emulator and on 480x800 resolution devices it's working.

BRIgeAdapter:

```
package com.brige.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.brige.MainActivity;
import com.brige.R;
import com.brige.json.ImageLoader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BRIgeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> itemList;

    public BRIgeAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

            holder.journal = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.smalljournal);
            holder.thumb_image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.smallthumb);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.smalltitle);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.smalldesc);
            holder.statId = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.smallstatID);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        itemList = data.get(position);

        if (itemList != null) {
            holder.journal.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_journal));
            holder.statId.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_statID));
            holder.journal.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

            String titleString = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_title);

            holder.title.setText(titleString);
            holder.title.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);
            holder.description.setText(itemList
                    .get(MainActivity.KEY_description));
            holder.description.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_image),
                    holder.thumb_image);

        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView journal, title, description, statId;
        ImageView thumb_image;
    }

}
```

ImageLoader:

```
package com.brige.json;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import com.brige.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                a.runOnUiThread(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the code of your Adapter.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mnvzgi94phls161/BRIgeAdapter.java   this is a my adapter

Comment: Post your code here.  No-one is going to download your code from dropbox.  It will also allow future people to see the problem (and answer). My guess is that you are not using the ViewHolder pattern correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the render lag is not the images being loaded in the background? Can you post the code where you setup your ImageLoader.

Comment: @Booger The ViewHolder pattern is actually applied very well in the code he posted. It's not that.

Comment: yes sure this is a my ImageLoader Class https://www.dropbox.com/s/5pown1hr2n4jvk0/ImageLoader.java realy sorry i am new on stackoverflow and i do not know how to post code on comments. sorry

Comment: Uhm.. Is that a custom implementation of an ImageLoader or are you using code from an existing solution? Consider using Google Volley or UniversalImageLoader. Another thing: how many items are we talking about in the ListView?

Comment: Actually, I had exact same problem, and solved it by switching the library I used from AQuery for image caching to Picasso.

Comment: There are many optimizations such as aborting requests that will not produce a visible result etc. Google Volley should have great support for aborting requests. I use UniversalImageLoader myself though.

Comment: yes sure i use ImageLoader.i found this imageloader class on this web-site (http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/09/loading-images-into-gridview-using-image-loader-from-a-json/) the  project idea is  to show first time 20 items and when  scroll end (last item position) add  for again 20 items. etc first time 20 items second time 40 . 60 . etc... program working perdect on 480X800 screen resolution but another resolution (more resolution) i have this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the library/implementation of your ImageLoader. I can recommend [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Comment: i found this library but  i do not know how to use this on my project :(  i am new android programming

Comment: Read from Quick Setup in the link in my post. Follow everything to the letter.